How to use AND statement within an IF statement in a complex nested array (Excel)
The following formula works:
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A:$C, SMALL(IF(Data!$A:$A = Template!$C$2, ROW(Data!$C:$C)), ROW(2:2)), 3, 1), "")}

But when I try to add an AND statement within the IF, it breaks down:
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$A:$C, SMALL(IF(AND(Data!$A:$A = $C$2, Data!$B:$B < 100), ROW(Data!$C:$C)), ROW(1:1)), 2, 1), "")

Ideally, I am trying to find the other person who share any projects with Harrison, Louis S.  I cant use filters because if I filter by Col A, it won't give me the name of the other person who shares projects with such person.
Below is an example of my data.
tab/sheet name: "Template"
Cell C2 = Harrison, Louis S.
tab/sheet: "Data"



Person
Commission %
Project Name




Jane Doe
50
Project A


Harrison, Louis S.
100
Project B


Harrison, Louis S.
50
Project A


John Doe
70
Project C


Mark Doe
30
Project D


Jane Doe
100
Project E


Harrison, Louis S.
70
Project D



What I want: For all Projects where the name is what is in Cell C2 ("Harrison, Louis S." in this case) and where Commission % < 100:
This is the result I am looking for:



Person
Commission %
Project Name




Jane Doe
50
Project A


Mark Doe
30
Project D



Please let me know if I need to provide more information. I appreciate the help, thank you!

Try to use the function AND(condition1, condition2).

AND will not work in an array type formula instead multiply the booleans: ((Data!$A:$A = Template!$C$2)*(Data!$C:$C < 100))

& is not the same as AND(). & will join ranges, AND() will return TRUE or FALSE dependent on (all) it's conditions. `(array)*(array) can be used to multiply conditions. TRUE equals 1, FALSE equals 0. If any of the conditions are 0, the previous result(s) are multiplied by 0, resulting in 0. This allows row wise comparison.
